# How do you choose which mortgage structure is appropriate when buying a home?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, calculation, first-time-home-buyer

My lease is up in 1 month, and I'm looking to buy a home in the next 4 weeks. I have narrowed it down to two that I am interested in.

I'm wondering about the type of mortgage I should get. Which combination of these variables would be best for me? How do I calculate?

- Down payment: I can do 3.5% (FHA) all the way through 20% (though 20% would be more difficult)
- Term: 15 year vs. 30 year fixed
- PMI: If not 20% down payment... pay up front, or over time? Or not at all? Or lender paid?
- If no PMI, HECL/double mortgage? 10-10-80 loan? 8-12-80?

Thank you for your assistance.

p.s. I have been averaging 19%/year in stocks, but started in 2009 so I have had crazy tail winds helping. I think I'd like to assume 8-10%/year as reasonable for average investing returns. So based on that, it seems like I want the largest mortgage possible, but I don't know how to calculate for PMI, impact on my income taxes, etc. Also assuming house price ~450k-650k and 2-5 years of residence.

Comment: Its ridiculous to buy a house for less than 5 years.

Comment: Why? With rates this low...can upgrade/rent it out after 2..

Comment: You can sell or rent it out, if the market is right. Prices can drop, and rental markets can be saturated.

Comment: asking the questions is a good start. But it is unrealistic to be able to start from scratch and be able to move into a place you haven't even found yet in only four weeks. Plan on extending the lease or going month-to-month.

Comment: I hope you're aware that 'buy a house in the next 4 weeks' doesn't mean 'own and move into a house in the next 4 weeks'.  Closing on a new house is usually a month or more process, even after you've had an offer accepted.

Comment: @ego - "...rent it out..." sounds perfect in theory -- the renters pay for it so you're at worst cashflow neutral. But what if you don't get renters? Rent on a $450K house is going to significantly limit your potential market, so it's not a guarantee that you'll always have someone in the house paying for it.

Comment: Loaning money to put to speculate on a single investment doesn't sound like a good idea to me. That way a small fluctuation can wipe out all your savings. While the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) doesn't directly apply to your case, the idea behind it does.

Comment: FHA loans have limits.  Check with your state.  Also, why would you wan't the `largest mortgage possible`.  You are buying a house not seeing how large a loan you can get.....

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors that you need to consider:

If you have already decided on the house. 
Did you prequalify for the mortgage loan - If so, did you lock in the rate.

If you have not already done than your research is still valid.

Consider two calculators first - Affordability + Mortgage calculator

1. http://www.bankrate.com/partners/sem/mortgage-calculator-rates-tl.aspx
2. http://www.realtor.com/mortgage/tools/affordability-calculator/

Advice :

1. If you can afford to pay 20% down then please do, Lesser monthly mortgage payment, you can save approx 400 $ per month, the above calculator will give you an exact idea.
2. If you can afford go for 15 years loan - Lower interest rate over 2-5 years period.
3. Do not assume the average ROI will + 8-10%. It all depends on market and has variable factors like city, area and demand.
4. In terms of Income your interest payment is Tax deductible at the end of the year.

Comment: http://www.realtor.com/advice/your-mortgage-payment-explained/?iid=finance_calculator_home-affordability-finance-advice

Comment: I am assuming ROI for return on stock investments. Not of the house. Hence why I was saying it might make more sense to put in under 20%. Does that change your advice at all?

Comment: Yes in that case my advice do change, 20% ROI on stocks is very good, but a comparable evaluation, do the maths (20% of X amount > PMI for 1 year).  PMI are only valid till you dont pay 20% of your inital loan value or your house gets appraised to the 20% of the remainder of loan for first 2 years. After 2 years its 78%.

Answer (score 1):

Go for 15 years loan - Lower interest rate over 2-5 years period.
If you can afford to pay 20% down then please do.
Do not assume the average ROI will +(8-10%). It all depends on market and has variable factors like city, area and demand.

Comment: I assume the OP meant 8 to 10% ROI on other investments he or she would make with money not tied up in a mortgage, not the ROI on the house itself.

Answer (score 0):

Down payment: Emphatically avoid PMI if at all possible; it's pouring money down the drain. Do 20% down if you can, or pay off enough to bring you above 20% and ask for PMI to be removed as soon as you can. Beyond that it's a matter of how much risk you want to accept and how long you'll own the place, and you'll have to run the numbers for the various alternatives -- allowing for uncertainty in your investments -- to guide your decision.

Do not assume you will be able to make a profit when you sell the house; that's the mistake which left many people under water and/or foreclosed on. Do not assume that you will be able to sell it quickly; it can take a year of more. Do not assume immediate or 100% occupancy it you rent it out; see many other answers here for more realistic numbers.... and remember that running a rental is a *business* and has ongoing costs and hassles. (You can contract those out, but then you lose a good percentage of the rent income.)

Double mortgage is another great way to dig yourself into a financial hole; it can be a bigger cost than the PMI it tries to dodge and is definitely a bigger risk. Don't.